# Giant Steps are what you take…

Tags: lyrics, meaning, song-title

The Police song "Walking on the moon" starts with the lyrics:

> Giant steps are what you take,
> walking on the moon.

Apart from the lyrical connection, is there any *musical* connection (however tenuous) between the song "Walking on the moon" and the jazz standard "Giant Steps"?

(I'd love for the answer to this question to be true!)

Comment: No, but that's too short for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Tempo-wise, definitely no.

Rhythm-wise, no. Raggae-ish skank versus jazz bop.

Hamony-wise, very different. *Walking on the moon* is pretty simple, the verses just alternate `Dm C`, *Giant Steps* is famous for its harmonic complexity.

Melody-wise, the is the only place I see a *tenuous* connection. "...are what you..." descends in thirds and the melody of *Giant Steps* starts by descending in thirds. But melodies moving by thirds is so common it would be like drawing a connection between to the songs because they are both in `4/4` time.

This was a fun question, and both songs are so great, I just wanted to do a side by side comparison of basic musical elements, even if it is pretty obvious to the ear there is no connection. The lead sheets I compared are below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Agreed, there is no musical connection but there MAY have been a psychological connection. Sting played jazz gigs in the early 1970’s and had a fondness for John Coltrane among other jazz greats. Maybe he used that line as a subtle homage to Coltrane.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to imagine singing those words "giant steps", especially with Sting's background, and not at least thinking of the jazz song.

Answer (score 0):

I can't detect any!  The words 'Giant steps' have a certain resonance if you know the Coltrane piece.  But that's all.  Pity.

Answer (score -1):

> "One small step for man, one giant leap for mankind"

Neil Armstrong - said while literally walking on the moon.

You don't per chance think that *this quote* - potentially the most famous quote said by anyone in any context during the whole 20th century - could *possibly* be the reference used in the song *Walking on the Moon*?

No, it has to refer to some obscure jazz term for sure.

Comment: Neil Armstrong didn't mention the moon in his quote. And although he used the words "giant" and "steps" he didn't use them _together_. However, you did get me thinking — the song "Walking on the moon" was written by **Sting**, and one of Neil Armstrong's astronaut colleagues was named **Buzz**, so there's a definite connection there!